# How can i get all tags from a mailchimp audience using API v3?

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using [mailchimp API v3](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php) in my PHP project.
What is the best (and efficient) way to get all TAGS at once from an audience (list) as Mailchimp does at campaign creation?
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZAQM.png)

Any example?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet as I think the problem is very complex. I have to call the service that gives the members and for each one, I have to get the tags (must do this as many times as the thousands of members). Sounds very weird and complex.

Answer (score 2):

for all the people who might face the same problem (and pull their hair) the answer is simple is this:

```
$response = $mailchimp->lists->listSegments($list_id);
print_r($response);
```

the response contains all the tags from the specified list

Answer (score 1):

```
$mailchimp->lists->listSegments($list_id)
```

returns array off tags + segments.
better to use this

```
$mailchimp->lists->tagSearch($list_id)
```